# how to attach keyup event from within jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a jQuery plugin, and inside of it I have an init function. Inside of this init-function I attach some events:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.gallery = function(options) {

        var init = function(self) {

            var main += '<input id="gallery-search">';

            //click event for the filter checkboxes
            $("body").on('click', self.selector+" .gallery-filter-checkbox",function(event) {
                self.data(filter( self ));
            });

            //capture input in the search box
            $('#gallery-search').keyup(function(){
                console.log('test');
            });

            self.html(output);

        }

    }( jQuery ));

}
```

The first one works just fine, but the second one doesn't work at all. I have tested it outside of the plugin scope and it works just fine so there is no syntax error, but probably an error in the way I try and attach the event?

Comment: Does `#gallery-search` element exist on page at the adding `keyup` event handler moment?

Comment: Thanks Regent... rookie-mistake. I had compiled all the html just before, but it wasn't actually rendered to the DOM until after the attachment. And I guess the other event actually allows me to do that since it attaches a listener to every click in BODY and THEN checks if the click was for the targeted element.

Comment: You are welcome. So you can switch to delegated event handler there as well:  `$(document).on('keyup', '#gallery-search', function() {`. [Delegated event handlers docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: That would suck up more system resources from the browser though right?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's why closest static parent is usually used instead of `document`/`body` to minimize unnecessary actions.

Comment: Regent, I added the html context in my original question, so you can post an answer, so you can get the credit and so I can mark solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `#gallery-search` is created dynamically, you can use [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#gallery-search', function() { ... });
```

If `self` represents static HTML element at page, you can use a little better (for performance) version:

```
self.on('keyup', '#gallery-search', function() { ... });
```

Or you can place event handler in code after element's insertion, if HTML will not be modified later:

```
self.html(output);
$('#gallery-search').keyup(function()
{
    console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`keyup()` is a shortcut for `bind('keyup',callback)` which will register some event handler on the elements that are already present in the DOM (not necessarily rendered). It won't work if the element is not present in DOM when it's defined. To do that you need to use `delegate()` which will attach some handler on an element which is currently available or in might be available in future.

From jQuery 1.7 onwards, it's recommended to use `on()` as it combines the functionality of bind / delegate / live.

on() can be used in two ways

```
$(selector).on('event',callback);
$(parentSelector).on('event','someChildSelector', callback);
```

First one is direct handler and second one is called delegated handler. 
If you're using first one to register event handlers, you've to make sure that element is present in the DOM at the time of registering just like `bind()`. So if you're adding new elements, you have to attach that handler again.

If you're using the second way, you don't have to worry about registering the handler again

```
$(document).on('click','.row',callback);
```

As document is always available, you callback will be registered as click handler for all the existing rows and any new row that you might add in the future.

I strongly recommend you read the `Direct and delegated events` section [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). They even explain about the performance benefits.

Now that you know how it works, you can fix it using `on()` either as a direct handler or as a delegated handler.

**EDIT :** It's better to use closest static parent than document/body when using on() to register delegated handlers. Thanks to Regent for suggesting that :)

```
   $('closestStaticParent').on('keyup','#gallery-search',function(){
        console.log('test');
   });
```